# Which is correct "above question" or "question above"? "Above mentioned" or "mentioned above"?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know which is more correct:
"above question" or "question above"? 
"Above mentioned" or "mentioned above"?

I have already read different explanations and I cannot understand which one is the most correct?

Many thanks

Comment: Related question, [The grammar behind 'above mentioned'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239396/the-grammar-behind-above-mentioned) and [Using “mentioned above” when speaking](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182937/using-mentioned-above-when-speaking) and [Can “above mentioned” be a noun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258350/can-above-mentioned-be-a-noun).

Answer (score 5):

Both are equally correct.  "Above" is both an adjective and a preposition.

> "Read the above question."

Here we have used "above" as an adjective that describes "question."

> "Read the question above."

Here we have used "above" as a preposition that indicates the position of the "question."

The tricky one is its opposite "below."  Whereas "below" is a preposition, it is not an adjective. We can only say:

> "Read the question below."

However, we cannot put "below" before the noun.  We cannot properly say, "Read the below question."

Comment: The two answers are nearly identical. What are you trying to do, win two Stanley Cups in one season?

Comment: I know, right!  I just saw that.  I don't know how that happened.  My computer must have hiccoughed.  I deleted the extra answer.

Comment: I thought it was funny.

Comment: Good.  So did I.

Comment: The "below" answer is exactly what I seek. Thank you.